# GtkWarning could not open display - how can I notify-send from my daemon

Tags: linux, ubuntu, python-2.7, gtk, upstart

I have a python-2.7.4 daemon script that uses the following command:

```
from os import popen
cmd = 'notify-send --icon=ICON_FILE --urgency=critical  -t 10000 \'SCRIPT_NAME\' \'Here is my message\''
popen('su USER -c -p \"'+cmd+'\"')
```

This command works fine from the python command shell as ROOT. However, it does not work when running as a daemon. The daemon runs fine (logging data as it is polled), but does not provide user feedback as desired.

The daemon is running on Mint (Ubuntu) using Upstart and a /etc/init/SCRIPT.conf file. The /var/log/upstart/SCRIPT.log file has the single entry after rebooting:

**/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/gtk-2.0/gtk/_*init*_.py:57: GtkWarning: could not open display   warnings.warn(str(e), _gtk.Warning)**

I find logged in users with the following command:

```
popen('users')
```

From what I have found otherwise, there are security issues with sending messages to other user displays and since the daemon runs from ROOT, it returns the above GtkWarning. How can I make my python daemon provide user feedback with osd and notify-send?

Answer (score 2):

The GTKWarning is not applicable to the problem with sending the notify-send. The daemon is, of course, running as root and needs to use the 'DISPLAY' variable to access the user's display.

```
export DISPLAY=:0
```

I fixed this by finding the display of the user with the 'w' command and changing this variable before sending the notify-send command. The daemon now correctly sends the notification to the user's DISPLAY.